# Terminal Browser + Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

I'm trying to avoid as much apps with a GUI on my PC as possible and the only one that I have a hard time finding a substitute for is Tor. Would using [Links](http://links.twibright.com/) (My favorite browser) with JavaScript disabled and routing all my internet traffic through Tor make me identifiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Using links, lynx, w3m or even curl or wget with Torsocks will show you as being different than a normal Tor user but they will not leak your IP. Torsocks is pretty good about that. I think you would be safer with one of those because you would not worry about things like rogue javascript or your browser giving away too much of your information but you would be more easily fingerprintable.

Comment: Welp. I ended up blocking all non-Tor traffic and resolving DNS over and Links didn't work with Torsocks so I guess I'll stick with the original one on safest mode.

Comment: Links does work with Torsocks. See the attached screenshot. Make sure that your tor daemon is running.